# Webscraping in R - choosing the right CSS selector/class or HTML element

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I have hard time to understand how to select the right element for Web-scraping the info I seek. I use the programming language R for this.

Many tutorials guide you through the [www.imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com) website
The structure there is kind of easy to follow and the elements to select are also more intuitive... but looking at other websites, this becomes more tricky.

Like for real estates websites:
https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/steiermark/graz-stadt/immobilie-mieten
I'd like to extract the link from the next-buttom.

Is there a straight-forward way to do this? I do use the "right mouse - insepct" thing...
And I copy the css-selector:
#root > section > section > section:nth-child(1) > section._1NnXN > ul > li._1QVg8 > a

How can I decide quickly, which element to select?
[image]

Thank you so much,
Nadine

Comment: Learn some basic html then read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and practice with [this](https://flukeout.github.io/)   You can then learn to specify your own patterns including reducing what the right click copy selector gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not easy, but there are some tricks

#### Look for 'human' tricks

For example, if you're after the prices from a page, open the page source (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> on mac with chrome) and <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> for the word 'price' - with some luck, the web devs who made the site *may* have coded in a css class specifically for the price, which makes it really easy to get! (that requires some luck, but it's worth a shot).

Some common names for ecommerce sites are 'product', 'price', 'image', 'specs' etc.

#### Use a browser addon

One of the most popular is [SelectorGadget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=en). You simply turn it on, move the mouse on to any element, click on it, and it will give you an xpath to that element.

#### Start with a high-level HTML element, and work your way down until you find what you're after

If other methods fail, start with one of the main sections of the page, then slowly add more refinement to the elements/classes in the selector until you arrive at the element you want to see.

For example, suppose the page consists of this simple HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="product">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="/images/product_10.png">
        </div>
        <div class="price">
          $22
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And say we want to get the price. We can see at the top of the HTML (inside the opening 'body' tag), that there's a div, then another div, so we can work down this chain like so:

```
raw_html <- '<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="product">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="/images/product_10.png">
        </div>
        <div class="price">
          $22
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>'

library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)


page_html <- read_html(raw_html)
page_html %>% 
  html_nodes("div")
# {xml_nodeset (4)}
# [1] <div class="jumbotron">\n      <div class="product">\n        <div class="image">\n          <img src="/images/product_10.png">\n</div>\n        <div cla ...
# [2] <div class="product">\n        <div class="image">\n          <img src="/images/product_10.png">\n</div>\n        <div class="price">\n          $22\n    ...
# [3] <div class="image">\n          <img src="/images/product_10.png">\n</div>
# [4] <div class="price">\n          $22\n        </div>

# Narrowing down
page_html %>% 
  html_nodes("div div")

# {xml_nodeset (3)}
# [1] <div class="product">\n        <div class="image">\n          <img src="/images/product_10.png">\n</div>\n        <div class="price">\n          $22\n    ...
# [2] <div class="image">\n          <img src="/images/product_10.png">\n</div>
# [3] <div class="price">\n          $22\n        </div>

# ..getting closer..
page_html %>% 
  html_nodes("div div div.price")
# {xml_nodeset (1)}
# [1] <div class="price">\n          $22\n        </div>

page_html %>% 
  html_nodes("div div div.price") %>% 
  html_text %>% 
  trimws
# [1] "$22"
```

Then we end up with the price (or whatever other element we wanted).

Comment: Worth adding in that in the browser Find box you can test out your revised css selectors as well. Even better would be to install an extension which allows you to quickly toggle off JS so you can run css selectors against what is actually returned by rvest. IMO, selector gadget is too verbose but useful as a starting point.